# Illegal Variable name when using tcsh

Tags: tcsh

```
set GIT_DIR=`(git rev-parse --git-dir')/hooks
mkdir -p "${GIT_DIR}"
curl -s -n -Lo "$repo_root/${GIT_DIR}/commit-msg" "https://gerrit.ericsson.se/tools/hooks/commit-msg"
```

when the above code is used in tcsh, its throwing error: Illegal Variable name .
Can please someone help with this

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to have

```
set GIT_DIR=`(git rev-parse --git-dir)`/hooks
```

Comment: Yes, that works. The problem in the OP's code was that (a) the parentheses were not nested inside the backticks and (b) the initial backtick was paired with an apostrophe rather than another backtick. Also, there's no particular reason to use parentheses, though it would be a good idea to use double quotes. I'm having trouble getting the backticks to display correctly, so replace the at-signs with backticks in this: `set GIT_DIR="@git rev-parse --git-dir@/hooks"`